# jquery - why if clause fires although condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, operators

I don't know whats going on...

I have this:

```
console.log("n="+n): 
console.log("longest.length="+longest.length);
console.log("longest.length/n="+longest.length/n);

if ( n=1 || longest.length/n != 1 ) { 
  // do something 
}
```

console says *n=4*, *longest.length=4* and *longest.length/n=1*

Still... do something fires... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not `longest.length == n`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `n==1` as opposed to `n=1`. You are setting `n` to `1` as opposed to checking it's value.

Comment: oh yes... I should have noticed that an hour ago... First answer. thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( n=1 || longest.length/n != 1 ) { 
  // do something 
}
```

should be

```
if ( n==1 || longest.length/n != 1 ) { 
  // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `n=1` comparison is actually an assignment. Try changing it to:

```
if ( n == 1 || longest.length/n != 1 ) { 
  // do something 
}
```